# Populate specific column in google sheet using google script

Tags: javascript, html, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm using google script in google sheet in order to populate the cell with data that I entered. First I made a form by using html where I store data I entered as object in html (image below).[image]

then i call the data I stored in html code with javascript in order to populate the targeted sheet(the last row of the first column)(image below), and it worked.

[image]

But then, I created the same form with the same code html but for now I want to populate the last row of the second column. I'm trying using the same code **appendRow**([null,data.name]), but the problem is it will populate the last row of the sheet. I tried to use **getRange** then **setValues** but it doesnt work.

Please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can refer to this sample code:

```
function appendToColumn() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("trial");
  var data = "Testing";
  //Get the column where you want to append the data
  var range = sheet.getRange("B1:B").getValues().flat();
  var row = range.filter(String).length;
  Logger.log(row);
  sheet.getRange(row+1,2).setValue(data);
}
```

### What it does?

1. Get the range of the column where you want to append your data
2. Get its value, use `array.flat()` to change 2-d array to 1-d array
3. Remove empty cell values using `array.filter()` and get its length
4. The length of the array should match the row count of your desired column
5. Increment the current row count and set its value

### Output:

Before:

[image]

After:

[image]

Comment: Glad to hear that. By the way, if we answered your question, please click the accept button.  By doing so, other people in the community, who may have the same concern as you, will know that theirs can be resolved. If the accept button is unavailable to you, feel free to tell me. [How to accept answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235)

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the last row in 'appenData' to

```
ws.getRange(ws.getLastRow() + 1, 2).setValue(data.name);
```

Comment: It works, but it gives me the same result as appendRow ([null,data.name]) which it takes the last row of the sheet not the column.